# How can I center content inside collection view with left and right contents shown inside collection view?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

[image]

I want to center the current image and show left and right images with space while scrolling inside collectionview. any suggestion?

Comment: Use `minimumInterItemSpacing` and `minimumLineSpacing` to define spacing between your cells.

Comment: Set yourImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill

Comment: you should check out.  https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

Comment: @RakeshaShastri How to set  minimumInterItemSpacing and minimumLineSpacing of collection view

Comment: @VikramSinha Have you done the same?

Comment: @Muju You can set it to your `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` instance or use the appropriate delegate.

Comment: @Muju have you gone through https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel